# How do I append a string to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append strings to a Pandas Dataframe, and then use the df.at function to assign values to them. Below are 2 snippets of code where I am using Pandas, in the first one, I am using a string input and appending the input as an index to the data frame. In the second one, I am trying to use a string input but am getting the following error.

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

**Snippet 1**

```
    allBooks = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Copies'])


    newBook = input("Enter the title of the book you wish to add ")
    newCopies = int(input("Enter the amount of copies of this book "))
    allBooks.append(newBook)
    allBooks.at[allBooks.item(newBook), 'Copies'] = newCopies
    allBooks.to_csv(r'totalInventory.csv')
```

**Snippet 2**

```
    userData = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fname','lname','dob','pwd'])


    fname = input("Please enter your first name. ")
    lname = input("Please enter your last name. ")
    dob = input("Please enter your DOB MM/DD/YYYY ")
    pwd = input("Type in the password you want to use. ")
    dobSeperate = dob.split("/")
    idChars = str(dobSeperate[1]) + str((dobSeperate[2])[2:4])
    userId = fname.lower() + idChars
    print("This is your user ID, please write it down:", userId)
    print("This is your password, please remember it:", pwd)
    users[userId] = pwd

    userData.append(userId)
    print(userId)
```

How do I change the code so that I can append the string in the second snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a string to a dataframe directly would not work.. for snippet 1, you can consider a slight change in the approach..

```
import pandas as pd

allBooks = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Copies'])
newBook = input("Enter the title of the book you wish to add ")
newCopies = int(input("Enter the amount of copies of this book "))
row = pd.DataFrame({'Title':[newBook], 'Copies':[newCopies]})
pd.concat([allBooks, row], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how snippet 1 is related to the question.

For snippet 2, you can add the user info to the dataframe from a list:

```
# include userId in columns
userData = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fname','lname','dob','pwd','userId'])
........

# append new user info
userData.loc(len(userData)+1) = [fname, lname, dob, pwd, userId]
```